# Spring 4 how to dynamically register new beans during runtime without refreshing application context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration, spring-4

I have a spring application that has run into some issues while upgrading from Spring 3.2 to Spring 4.2.

The application has standard XML based bean configuration that it loads into the application context, but also during runtime used a `GenericApplicationContext` to register new bean definitions, which are shared `JmsTemplate`s that were to be declared and reused as needed as beans on the application context.

Apparently this was okay in Spring 3 but not Spring 4, and I am wondering how I can replicate this behavior in Spring 4, without having to refresh the application context every time I register a new bean, therefore destroying all previously registered beans that I still need?

_____Edit: Additional info_____

The application additionally uses conventional XML configuration to specify a number of beans.

_____Edit: example method______

```
private void createAndRegisterJmsTemplateBeanDefinition(
    final String connectionFactoryBeanName,
    final String jmsDestinationBeanName, final String location,
    final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    final javax.jms.Destination destination) {

    final BeanDefinitionBuilder bDBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .rootBeanDefinition("org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate");

    if (connectionFactoryBeanName == null) {
        bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("connectionFactory", connectionFactory);
    } else {
        bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("connectionFactory",
                genericContext.getBean(connectionFactoryBeanName));
    }

    if (jmsDestinationBeanName == null) {
        bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("defaultDestination", destination);
    } else {
        bDBuilder.addPropertyValue("defaultDestination",
                genericContext.getBean(jmsDestinationBeanName));
    }

    genericContext.registerBeanDefinition(location,
            bDBuilder.getBeanDefinition());
}
```

Where the class that this method in implements ApplicationContextAware

```
implements ApplicationContextAware
```

and the genericContext is either created by:

```
genericContext = new GenericApplicationContext();
```

or

```
genericContext = new GenericApplicationContext(context);
```

where "context" is ApplicationContext set by:

```
public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.context = applicationContext;      
}
```

which is a required method to implement from ApplicationContextAware

The error that is thrown when `genericContext.getBean(bean)` is called while the code is still registering beans.

Placing `genericContext.refresh()` after the registration of new beans does not fix the issue, as this removes all other beans off the application context which are still needed.

Comment: I would expect that still to work, what doesn't work any more and how do you register the beans (and/or retrieve them).

Comment: @M.Deinum Please see my edit above

Comment: I probably lack a part of the picture but when are you registering the beans? During startup of really during runtime of the application? You would need to call `refresh` at some point as that wil initialize the context based on the registered bean definitions.

Comment: @M.Deinum The app also uses conventional XML configuration that specifies a few beans. The app in the code I showed above additionally tries to register a bunch of new beans @ runtime. The beans it tries to wire @ runtime are a bunch of JMS templates which hold info on JMS message queues and topics, and the templates that it tries to wire as beans are determined based off which particular queues and topics it tries to use at runtime.

Comment: The odd thing is that before when it was running Spring 3.2, not a single .refresh() call was made anywhere, and it ran fine. Only after the update did the issue occur. Simply toggling the spring version in pom.xml between 3.2 and 4.2 causes and fixes the issue.

Comment: Without a refresh the context wouldn't be properly started (and there have been quite some additions in the different versions between 3.2 and 4.2).

Comment: @M.Deinum, so in other words, there is no means of adding beans to the running application context at runtime without inevitably having to wipe clean all previously existing beans?

Comment: Beans aren't BeanDefinitions... Also refreshing shouldn't wipe anything it should proces the registered bean definitions and create beans out of them.

Comment: @M.Deinum So are you saying it is possible? If so please demonstrate with an example.